# How to pass data from webpage to iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to password marked in web page to my iPhone application. If I paste it to clipboard then I need to run my app in background which is not possible in iPhone. So, how I should do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more of what you want to do, it is a bit vague

Answer (score 3):

You can define a Custom URL Scheme in your iPhone app. Then you can link to your iPhone app using a regular HTML link, so for example `<a href="yourapp://mydata">Click here to go to my app</a>`. For more information about this, go to the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html) (scroll to the part about Custom URL schemes). You can also find a lot of information about this by [googling](http://www.google.com/?q=Custom+URL+Scheme+ios).